# Efficient pagination of MongoDB aggregation?

Tags: mongodb

For efficiency, the Mongo documentation recommends that limit statements immediately follow sort statements, thus ending up with the somewhat nonsensical:

```
 collection.find(f).sort(s).limit(l).skip(p)
```

I say this is somewhat nonsensical because it seems to say take the first l items, and then drop the first p of those l.   Since p is usually larger than l, you'd think you'd end up with no results, but in practice you end up with l results.

Aggregation works more as you'd expect:

```
collection.aggregate({$unwind: u}, {$group: g},{$match: f}, {$sort: s}, {$limit: l}, {$skip: p})
```

returns 0 results if p>=l.

```
collection.aggregate({$unwind: u}, {$group: g}, {$match: f}, {$sort: s}, {$skip: p}, {$limit: l})
```

works, but the documentation seems to imply that this will fail if the match returns a result set that's larger than working memory.    Is this true?   If so, is there a better way to perform pagination on a result set returned through aggregation?

Source:  the "Changed in version 2.4" comment at the end of this page:  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/

Answer (score 11):

In MongoDB cursor methods (i.e. when using `find()`) like `limit`, `sort`, `skip` can be applied in any order => order does not matter. A `find()` returns a cursor on which modifications applied. Sort is always done before limit, skip is done before limit as well. So in other words the order is: **sort -> skip -> limit**.

Aggregation framework does not return a DB cursor. Instead it returns a *document* with results of aggregation. It works by producing intermediate results at each step of the pipeline and thus the order of operations really matters.

I guess MongoDB does not support order for cursor modifier methods because of the way it's implemented internally.

You can't paginate on a result of aggregation framework because there is a single document with results only. You can still paginate on a regular query by using skip and limit, but a better practice would be to use a range query due to it's efficiency of using an index.

**UPDATE:**

Since v2.6 Mongo aggregation framework returns a cursor instead of a single document. Compare: [v2.4](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.4/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) and [v2.6](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/).

Comment: I am paginating on an aggregation now, but we only have ~50,000 items in the collection.   I'm just wondering if this will blow up on me as the collection grows.   If there's no workaround, I'll have to do more denormalization to avoid the aggregation.

Comment: If results of aggregation command do not fit within a size of 1 document you will get an error. Usually you tweak your schema/data to match most common queries when you work with no-sql DBs. ;)

Answer (score 1):

> The documentation seems to imply that this (aggregation) will fail if the match returns a result set that's larger than working memory. Is this true?

No. You can, for example, aggregate on a collection that is larger than physical memory without even using the `$match` operator. It might be slow, but it should work. There is no problem if `$match` returns something that is larger than RAM.

Here are the actual pipeline limits.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/

The `$match` operator solely does not cause memory problems. As stated in the documentation, `$group` and `$sort` are the usual villains. They are cumulative, and might require access to the entire input set before they can produce any output. If they load too much data into physical memory, they will fail.

> If so, is there a better way to perform pagination on a result set returned through aggregation?

I has been correctly said that you cannot "paginate" (apply `$skip` and `$limit`) on the result of the aggregation, because it is simply a MongoDB document. But you can "paginate" on the intermediate results of the aggregation pipeline.

Using `$limit` on the pipeline will help on keeping the result set within the 16 MB bounds, the maximum BSON document size. Even if the collection grows, you should be safe.

Problems could arise with `$group` and, specially, `$sort`. You can create "sort friendly" indexes to deal with them if they do actually happen. Have a look at the documentation on indexing strategies.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/

Finally, be aware that `$skip` does not help with performance. On the contrary, they tend to slow down the application since it forces MongoDB to scan every skipped document to reach the desired point in the collection.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/

Comment: In pagination scenarios, skip will be small -- nobody views page #2056.   So that's not a concern.

Comment: Lots of great info, but not quite answering my question.  It's clear from the documentation that `$sort` followed by `$limit` in a pipeline is safe for my needs.  My question is: what about `$sort` followed by a small `$skip` followed by a `$limit`?

Comment: AFAICT, using a small `$skip` an then `$limit` after a `$sort` is safe.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB recommendation of [$sort preceding $limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#sort-limit-memory-optimization) is absolutely true as when it happens it optimizes the memory required to do the operation for top n results.

It just that the solution you proposes doesn't fit your use case, which is pagination.

You can modify your query to to get the benefit from this optimization.

```
collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: u
  }, 
  {
    $group: g
  },
  {
    $match: f
  }, 
  {
    $sort: s
  }, 
  {
    $limit: l+p
  },
  { 
    $skip: p
  }
]);
```

or for `find` query

```
 collection.find(f).sort(s).limit(l+p).skip(p)
```

**Though, as you can see the with big pagination the memory will grow more and more even with this optimization.**