# Paging results of aggregation pipeline with spring data mongodb

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I am having a bit of trouble with paging the results of an aggregation pipeline. After looking at [In spring data mongodb how to achieve pagination for aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34427241/in-spring-data-mongodb-how-to-achieve-pagination-for-aggregation) I came up with what feels like a hacky solution.  I first performed the match query, then grouped by the field that I searched for, and counted the results, mapping the value to a private class:

```
private long getCount(String propertyName, String propertyValue) {
    MatchOperation matchOperation = match(
        Criteria.where(propertyName).is(propertyValue)
    );
    GroupOperation groupOperation = group(propertyName).count().as("count");
    Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(matchOperation, groupOperation);
    return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, Athlete.class, NumberOfResults.class)
        .getMappedResults().get(0).getCount();
}

private class NumberOfResults {
    private int count;

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

This way, I was able to provide a "total" value for the page object I was returning:

```
public Page<Athlete> findAllByName(String name, Pageable pageable) {
    long total = getCount("team.name", name);
    Aggregation aggregation = getAggregation("team.name", name, pageable);
    List<Athlete> aggregationResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(
        aggregation, Athlete.class, Athlete.class
    ).getMappedResults();
    return new PageImpl<>(aggregationResults, pageable, total);
}
```

You can see that the aggregation to get the total count of results is not too different from the **actual aggregation** that I want to perform:

```
MatchOperation matchOperation = match(Criteria.where(propertyName).is(propertyValue));
SkipOperation skipOperation = skip((long) (pageable.getPageNumber() * pageable.getPageSize()));
LimitOperation limitOperation = limit(pageable.getPageSize());
SortOperation sortOperation = sort(pageable.getSort());
return newAggregation(matchOperation, skipOperation, limitOperation, sortOperation);
```

This definitely worked, but, as I was saying, it feels hacky.  Is there a way to get the count for the PageImpl instance without essentially having to run the query twice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your question has helped me get around the same problem of paging with aggregation and so I did a little digging and came up with a solution to your problem. I know it's a bit late but someone might get use out of this answer. I am in no way a Mongo expert so if what I am doing is bad practice or not very performant please don't hesitate to let me know.

Using group, we can add the root documents to a set and also count.

```java
group().addToSet(Aggregation.ROOT).as("documents")
       .count().as("count"))
```

Here is my solution for almost the exact same problem you were facing.

```java
private Page<Customer> searchWithFilter(final String filterString, final Pageable pageable, final Sort sort) {
    final CustomerAggregationResult aggregationResult = new CustomerAggregationExecutor()
        .withAggregations(match(new Criteria()
                .orOperator(
                    where("firstName").regex(filterString),
                    where("lastName").regex(filterString))),
            skip((long) (pageable.getPageNumber() * pageable.getPageSize())),
            limit(pageable.getPageSize()),
            sort(sort),
            group()
                .addToSet(Aggregation.ROOT).as("documents")
                .count().as("count"))
        .executeAndGetResult(operations);
    return new PageImpl<>(aggregationResult.getDocuments(), pageable, aggregationResult.getCount());
}
```

CustomerAggregationResult.java

```java
@Data
public class CustomerAggregationResult {

  private int count;
  private List<Customer> documents;

  public static class PageableAggregationExecutor {

    private Aggregation aggregation;

    public CustomerAggregationExecutor withAggregations(final AggregationOperation... operations) {
      this.aggregation = newAggregation(operations);
      return this;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public CustomerAggregationResult executeAndGetResult(final MongoOperations operations) {
        return operations.aggregate(aggregation, Customer.class, CustomerAggregationResult.class)
            .getUniqueMappedResult();
    }

  }
}
```

Really hope this helps.

EDIT: I had initially created a generic PageableAggregationResult with List but this returns a IllegalArgumentException as I pass PageableAggregationResult.class with no type for T. If I find a solution for this I will edit this answer as I want to be able to aggregate multiple collections eventually.

Comment: I just got the notification about your reply.  I haven't really looked at this too much after initially posting it a while ago.  And now my team tries to avoid spring data with mongo, and we mostly use the mongo driver now.  But I'll mark this as the answer (without trying it) because your approach seems decent.